# jQuery each: array not be filled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am using `each` function of jQuery selector to go through elements. Then I just want to write them into an Array and post it. This is my code:

```
if(domains.length === 0) {
    var data = "skip";
} else {
    var data = [];

    $(".domain_row").each(function (index) {
        var label = $(this).find('.r_label');
        var myData = new Array();
        myData['domain'] = $(this).find('.r_domain').html();
        if(label.hasClass('label-success')) myData['type'] = "register";
        data[index] = myData;
    });
}

$.post("./index.php?domains_ajax", {
    action: "add",
    product: $("#product").val(),
    data: data,
}, function (response) {
    if(response == "true") window.location = "./cart.php?a=view";
    else sweetAlert("Fehler!", "Leider ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.", "error");
});
```

In case `data` is the string `skip`, it works. But in the `else` case it is not working. This is the Array directly after the `each`:

[image]

But - unfortunately - this is all what PHP receives (`var_dump($_POST);`):

```
array(2) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(3) "add"
  ["product"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

The data field is missing. It works - as I said before - if data is only a string or even an Array with alphanumerical values.

Comment: We don't see your PHP program, so I don't know what your program is supposed to be doing. Why are you expecting so much from giving an empty array as `data`? If you aren't giving anything for `data` then why are you expecting anything?

Comment: My guess is that `myData` should be an `object`  instead of  an `array`. Unlike `php`, `js` treats `object` and `array` differently. Replace `var myData = new Array();` with `var myData = {}`. Are you aware that, you are getting `array` of an `array` in console ?

Comment: I don't thing seeing the PHP actually matters here.  He's showing you what is being sent to it, and it's not getting the right values.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: It only dumps the data.

Comment: @fauxserious: Correct.

Comment: @Jashwant: Thank you, that was the mistake ;-)

Comment: I would suggest to delete this question.

Comment: @Jashwant: If you can name a reason for this...

Comment: Because, I think, this is not going to help other users. Please, look at the 'close'  link below question. 3 users have already voted for closing it.

Comment: @Jashwant: Correct, but the reason for their voting is not applying here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.map()`, [doc here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), instead of 'each', also use `push` instead of `arr[index] = value`.

```
var arr = [];
arr['a']='A';
arr['b']= 'B';
var data = [];
data.push(arr);
```

output:

```
data
[Array[0]
    a: "A"
    b:"B"
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]]
```

Comment: I tried `push` , but it does not work. Finally, it works with `var myData = {};`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the html, I'm going to be making some assumptions but try this for the else section:

```
var data = [];

$(".domain_row").each(function () {
    var label = $(this).contents().find('.r_label');
    var myData = [];
    myData['domain'] = $(this).contents().find('.r_domain').html();
    if(label.hasClass('label-success')) myData['type'] = "register";
    data.push(myData);
});
```

Comment: I also tried this notation (also `push` and `[]`), but it does not work. Finally, it works with `var myData = {};`. Thank you!